# SQL Looping through results

Tags: sql

I do a select and it brings back a list of IDs. I then want to call another procedure for each ID that calculates a result, so I end up with a list of results.

How can I do this? I need some kind of loop but I am not very good at SQL.

Edit: Microsoft SQL 2008, and purely in SQL

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What is your front-end application written in? MySQL, PHP or others?

Comment: what language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: We need more content in order to help - what table(s) & their columns, and what specifically are you wanting to calculate?

Comment: Loops/cursors are generally slow and it is almost always possible to replace them with SQL that doesn't have loops or cursors, especially in SQL 2008

Comment: I don't see how... I want to run a function on every user in my database, therefore I need to loop through them all surely?

Comment: Looping bad, never think of looping as your first solution. You need to start thinking in sets. Tell us what the proc you want to call does and we can give you a set-based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a user defined function that takes in the ID and returns the calculated result you can then get that result for each ID with a query like this:

```
SELECT id, DatabaseYouUsed.dbo.functionYouWrote(id)
FROM DatabaseYouUsed.dbo.TableWithIDs
```

Comment: I thought this only works with UDFs, not stored procedures. It doesn't seem to work in SQL2008 R2

Comment: That's pretty much like looping. I avoid using scalar udfs becasue they act row-by-row.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a stored procedure that calls the select to get the IDs, use a cursor on the result list and call the other procedure for each ID. All inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If one row generates one result:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(x int) RETURNS int AS BEGIN
    RETURN x * 2
END
GO
SELECT id, x, dbo.f(x) FROM my_table
```

If one row might generate more than one result:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(x int) RETURNS @r TABLE(result int) AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @r VALUES(x)
    INSERT INTO @r VALUES(x * 2)
    RETURN
END
GO
SELECT t.id, t.x, r.result FROM my_table t CROSS APPLY dbo.f(t.x) r
```